# New sessions being created on route with Express 4 + Passport JS (LocalStrategy) + MongoDB (Mongoose) + Sessions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

Could someone explain why a new session is being created each time I make a call to my express server.

The problem is that, once a new session is created it doesn't contain the user id against the passport property.

The architecture in the frontend is 2 html pages, which I'm serving via get routes.
(1) html page is the sign in form. 
(2) html page is a single page ember app which the user can only access once authenticated (working)

I get and post data via jQuery $.ajax - it's almost as if each time I make a request, I get a new session. Very odd.

**partial app.js**

```
server.use(cookieParser());
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
server.use(session({
    name: settings.sessionName,
    secret: settings.secret,
    cookie: { maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    store: new MongoStore({
        db: settings.database.name
    })
}));
server.use(passport.initialize());
server.use(passport.session());

require("./server/config/passport.js")(server, passport);
require("./server/routes.js")(server, passport);
```

**passport.js**

```
module.exports = function (server, passport) {
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var User = require('../schemas/user');

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user._id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function (error, user) {
            if (!error) done(null, user);
            else done(error, null);
        });
    });

    passport.use("local", new LocalStrategy({
                usernameField: 'email',
                passwordField: 'password',
                passReqToCallback: true
            },
            function (req, email, password, done) {
                User.findOne({ 'emailAddress': email }, function (error, user) {
                    if (error) {
                        return done(error);
                    }
                    if (!user) {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                    if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            })
    );
};
```

Anything will help at this point. Tearing my hair out!

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! I found the solution.

I was not passing the session secret into the cookie parser. Problem Solved!

Here's the fix:

**partial app.js**

```
server.use(cookieParser(settings.secret));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
server.use(session({
    name: settings.sessionName,
    secret: settings.secret,
    cookie: { maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    store: new MongoStore({
        db: settings.database.name
    }),
}));
```

The cookie parser needs to have the same secret as the express session.